# Why should I usually choose the socket protocol for implementing other protocols?

Tags: sockets, http, protocols

Suppose I want to implement a client for FTP and, maybe, for SFTP as well. A programming language is irrelevant. So I go ahead and choose a socket library for the programming language X and implement an FTP client. And that's it.

My question is, why did I have to choose a socket library or the socket protocol? Why neither HTTP library, nor ICMP, nor SSH, nor IP, nor anything else?

Comment: You're going to have to invest your own time in studying networking protocols and communications. There's a lot of information in RFC documents that explain more in depth on how protocols work.. For example: SMTP Protocol here... https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0821.txt Here's a decent looking overview but... you're asking the wrong quesiton for this site. http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/networking/guide/netcategories.html

Comment: Sockets is an API, not a protocol. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @SteveKline, really?????? whayyyyy!!!! are you sure?????? okk!!!!!

Comment: Think of it this way, if you want to talk to someone in another country, you have to learn their language and how to communicate with someone that speaks that language. The same principal applies, you have to learn how to make your application communicate with any of these protocol servers.

Comment: @SteveKline, you didn't understand my question.

Comment: I think the question/answer is in your textbook... This isn't the place to cheat on your homework. Ask your question in the proper context next time please.

Answer (score 3):

> ... why did I have to choose a socket library or the socket protocol? Why neither HTTP library, nor ICMP, nor SSH, nor IP, nor anything else?

You did not need to to chose a socket library. There are a variety of higher level libraries in the various programming languages which just let you use the application protocol without bothering you with the socket layer. Examples for HTTP are bindings to libcurl for various languages, LWP for Perl, requests for Python... .

> ... for implementing other protocols?

Of course if you want to **implement** instead of just use the application protocol yourself you explicitly decide to not use any of the existing libraries for this specific protocol. You then should use a layer which is below the protocol you want to implement. For implementing protocols like HTTP this would be the transport layer (i.e. use the sockets API), but for implementing higher level protocols like SOAP or REST over HTTP this could be the HTTP layer (i.e. use some HTTP library).

In case of FTP the next lower layer is transport layer, so you need to use the socket API. In case of SFTP you maybe can use a library implementing the SSH protocol since SFTP is a protocol using the SSH protocol.

Comment: `You did not need to to chose a socket library. ` -- what else could I've chosen?

Comment: `For implementing protocols like HTTP this would be the transport layer (i.e. use the sockets API),` -- http is on the 7th level, whereas sockets are on the 5th, so why not to chose anything from the level 6?

Comment: @Sojo: There are no presentation  and session layers with HTTP. But if you for example implement HTTPS then you don't use the socket API but need to use the SSL/TLS API, i.e. level 5. Apart from that, OSI layers 5..7 do not really reflect how many important protocols work. It is a nice theory but the practice is more dirty. That's why these are often merged together.

Comment: @Sojo:  "...what else could I've chosen" - this depends what you want to implement. If you want to do SOAP/REST you usually choose a HTTP API unless your really want to re-implement all the HTTP stuff. If you want to do HTTPS you use SSL/TLS. Of course if you want to have tight control over the transport you need to use a transport layer API.

Answer (score 0):

You see FTP, SFTP , HTTP, SSH  are Application Layer protocols.

All application layer protocols uses services provided by Transport layer.

Sockets works at transport layers.

ICMP and IP are Network layer protocols.

All protocols of application layers internally uses socket either TCP or UDP

Comment: does that answer my question?